# Trying translate crystal report if-else to c# if-else

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to rewrite the below statement to a c# statement so that I can use if in my program. I don't understand crystal report fomula enough to get it rewritten.

If Not IsNull({RET_USER_INFORMATION.TX_PHONE_WORK}) And Length (ToText({RET_USER_INFORMATION.TX_PHONE_WORK},0,"")) > 1 Then "(" & Mid (ToText({RET_USER_INFORMATION.TX_PHONE_WORK},0,""), 1, 3) & ") " & Mid (ToText({RET_USER_INFORMATION.TX_PHONE_WORK},0,""), 4, 3) &" - "& Mid (ToText({RET_USER_INFORMATION.TX_PHONE_WORK},0,""), 7, 4) Else "";

Answer (score 0):

```
 string _foo = RET_USER_INFORMATION !=null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(RET_USER_INFORMATION.TX_PHONE_WORK) ?  RET_USER_INFORMATION.TX_PHONE_WORK.ToString() : String.Empty;

 if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_foo))
 {
   return  String.Format("({0}){1}-{2}", _foo.Substring(0,3), _foo.Substring(3,3), _foo.Substring(6,4));
 }
 else
 {
   return String.Empty;
 }
```